# Count number of parse user returned null

Tags: android, count, parse-platform

I am trying to count number of user in my parse db and pass it to my sliding menu as a counter. However, it is always returned as null (I have more than 100users in parse user db). My code in the sliding menu as follows:

Any idea?

```
countuser = 0;
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Success
                    mUsers = users;


                    countuser = mUsers.size();

                }

            }
        });
```

I want to pass the counuser to my navigation item :

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "("+ countuser +")"));
```

Comment: check the docs "Rest api - section Counting Objects"

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the documentation under [Android, Queries, Counting Objects](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-counting).

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
// set any filters...

query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // all good
            countuser = count;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in case that someone came here:
in new parse-server you can try this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

the `scoreList.size()` return the count